# BASH - Check if unnamed pipe is empty

Tags: bash, pipe

My problem is, I want a script which reads content from a pipe, checks if it's empty and output it if not, as seen here:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(cat -)
if [ -n "$var" ]
then
    echo "$var"
else
    echo "Pipe was empty"
fi
```

The problem is, cat reads from stdin, if the pipe is empty. Is there any way to prevent cat from doing that? Or is cat the wrong tool to use here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `read -t 0 -N 0` to detect if data is available on stdin. Use `test -t 0` or `tty` to try to detect if a pipe is connected to stdin.

Comment: I believe `-t 0` and `-N 0` are redundant.

Comment: Any way to put that together in a script, because I'm not sure how to realize that. Sorry, but I don't use read very often (only read -n or read as is)

Comment: `if test -t 0; then echo "None"; else echo "$(cat -)"; fi` Just figured out by trial and error

Answer (score 2):

`test -t 0`, didn't work in my case, and people [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456750/detect-presence-of-stdin-contents-in-shell-script) say it's "non-deterministic" or something. I like the solution of `wc -c` (count bytes), nice and simple. Empty input has 1 byte, whereas a single character e.g. `echo "a" | wc -c` gives 2

```
| (read line; if [ $(echo "$line" | wc -c) -gt 1 ]; then echo "$line"; fi) |
```

This output remains pipe-able, thanks to the brackets around `read; if ...` See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15170225/2668831)

Comment: You'll also need the option `-t` (timeout), otherwise `read` will wait for user input in case of an empty pipe.